# user defined variable inside awk

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

Hi i have a script with below content

```
line="17"

awk '/$line/,/\/>/{printf "%s ",$0}/\/>/{print ""}' out.txt > temp.txt

cat temp.txt
```

it is not displaying any output but below query is giving the result i want

```
awk '/"17"/,/\/>/{printf "%s ",$0}/\/>/{print ""}' out.txt > temp.txt
```

I have used the awk inside script in different ways as below but no use

```
awk -v xyz="$line" '/xyz/,/\/>/{printf "%s ",$0}/\/>/{print ""}' out.txt > temp.txt
awk  "/$line/,/\/>/{printf '%s ',$0}/\/>/{print ''}" out.txt > temp.txt
```

and Is there any way to achive same along with exact match to $line ( like grep -w $line )..

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash doesn't substitute variable within single quoted strings.

Any easy way to check what you're doing is:

```
echo '/$line/,/\/>/{printf "%s ",$0}/\/>/{print ""}'
```

There are several ways to achieve what you want, this one seems quite readable:

```
awk '/"'$line'"/,/\/>/{printf "%s ",$0}/\/>/{print ""}'
```

Comment: can you please give me a solution to achieve the above mentioned requirement

Comment: I need to match $line exactly and it contains "number"  ( number in b/w quotes ) inside it. Can you PLEASE help me in that case

Comment: ahh I see... just add the double quotes. I already told you how to test the substitution...

Comment: its not working even after adding double quotes like awk /"$line"'/,/\/>/{printf "%s ",$0}/\/>/{print ""}' out.txt > temp.txt